# legal envelope size for 8.5x11 size letter?

Tags: print-design

I need to design a legal envelope (just put address and company logo) that is to be used with a 8.5x11 size letter.... what dimensions should the envelope be? also wondering if there's a template I can use... new to this, and would very much appreciate your help!!

[image]

Edits:

Do I just need to design this side? i.e. put logo and address to a template I find.  Just wanted to make sure I don't need to worry about the backside. Btw I knw this template is no. 9, not no. 10.

Comment: The standard US sizes for envelopes are [here](http://www.papersizes.org/us-envelope-sizes.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Just a standard **#10** envelope is customary. 4.125" x 9.5"

https://www.envelopes.com/envelope-sizes

[#10 direct link](https://www.envelopes.com/envelopes/control/product/%7Ecategory_id=REGULAR/%7Eproduct_id=10R-28W)

Note that for envelope design, *anything* which bleeds will *dramatically* increase production costs. It's best to leave at least 1/16" space around all edges.

There are 2 basic ways to get envlopes printed:

1. The envelopes are run already folded and glued and the press merely
   adds the imprint on the pre-bound envelope
2. Flat sheets are printed, then each is trimmed, folded and glued.

---

## 1

For #1 above, bleeds can be problematic. Because the envelope is already folded, there's no trimming of the stock. So a bleed means that ink literally runs off the side of the printed stock. This is *not* good. So customarily you need to leave a margin around all sides - I've had print providers ask for anywhere from 1/32" margin to 1/8" margin. But they all want a margin.

If (for #1) you want to print something on the flap, that means the envelopes all must be *opened* before running through a press. That time to open the envelopes costs. So printing on the flap costs more.

Using preformed envelopes generally saves money on production. It does, however, mean you need to adhere to these restrictions.

---

## 2

For #2 above, you can do pretty much anything you want. The envelopes are printed like anything else, then the cost of trimming, glueing and folding is all reflected in the production costs. Flat run envelopes generally cost more due to this, there is far more design freedom with this production method though.

---

So, ultimately things all come down to what you want to pay for production of the envelopes.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Just updated the question with an image - I only need to design that one side right? Thanks!!!

Comment: @roarsandmeows Well, that image is a **#9** envelope which is customarily used for reply envelopes (inside the #10). So, depending upon intent, the #9 may not be the correct size to use.Regarding the "one side" that's kind of your call. Most designs on the flap side will increase production costs though.

Comment: @roarsandmeows - which print process are you going to use? Is it lithography, inkjet printing? Do you want to design the entire envelope, and have it custom made to your specifications, or do you intend to buy ready made envelopes and simply have them overprinted?

Comment: I'm not looking to design the entire envelope, just have them overprinted.  I only need to design this one side?